# Delay a live audio signal 30 sec or more

Tags: field-recording

Hi,

Im looking for way to delay an audio signal for more than 30 seconds. I know how to do this with the help of my computer but i cant seem to find another way, a way where i dont need my computer.

/m

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way by using Pure Data + Raspberry Pi + USB Sound card :)

Comment: That's actually not a bad suggestion :D Cheap as well. Requires a display and mouse+keyboard to setup though.

Answer (score 0):

look into broadcast delay units from the radio world like this one
http://www.sonifex.co.uk/redbox/rbpd2_ld.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Most digital crossovers for speakers have the ability to delay.  XTA makes many different kinds.